# How to change TM_FILENAME_BASE when creating snippets in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I have a file named `"Card.styled.js"`

I want to create a snippet to write easier the styled component:

```
"styled": {
  "prefix": "styled",
  "body": [
    "import styled from \"styled-components\"",
    "",
    "export const ${1:${TM_FILENAME_BASE}} = styled.$2`",
    "",
    "${3}",
    "`"
  ]
}
```

But `${1:${TM_FILENAME_BASE}}` is returning me `Card.styled`.

I want to return only `Card` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Card.styled` is the correct `TM_FILENAME_BASE` of `Card.styled.js`.  You will have to modify it further.

You want something like this:

```
  "styled": {
    "prefix": "styled",
    "body": [
      "import styled from \"styled-components\"",
      "",
      "export const ${1:${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*?)\\..*/$1/}} = styled.$2`",
      "",
      "${3}",
      "`"
    ]  
  }
```

`(.*?)\\..*` get everything before the first `.` into capture group 1

Match the entire filename_base and replace it with only capture group 1 .